# How to run angularjs app on nodejs? Got error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm still learning angular.
When I'm trying to run my code i got an error like this message:

```
> electron@4.0.7 postinstall C:\electron-quick-start\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

Downloading tmp-12340-0-electron-v4.0.7-win32-x64.zip
Error: read ECONNRESET
C:\electron-quick-start\node_modules\electron\install.js:49
  throw err
  ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@4.0.7 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@4.0.7 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-12T07_35_01_086Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Install electron globally in your PC

Comment: Please add the error message **as text** to the question as well. Otherwise this question won't be searchable for future readers

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal What will mean this globally? Give me more information please

Answer (score 0):

Use this command for installation :

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

You can also use [quick start electron js](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

Your NodeJS version is also important check your node version with :

`node -v`

And please read this document
[Electron Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/upgrading-node)

Comment: What is doing this "node -v" ?

Comment: learn your nodejs version and read to part of nodejs requirements on the electronjs documentation